# Отражение легкого DDOS (флуда)

Tags: защита, iptables, ddos

Подскажите действенные методы по сабжу. Может какие либо правила? Сам изучал, но кроме как банить адреса в iptables не научился, как не прискорбно. Хотелось бы увидеть что то наглядное. Думаю это поможет многим, спасибо:)

Answer (score 1):

для начала определите какие именно сервисы DDOSятся. Доступ к ним можно либо блокировать по IP (ваш метод, но уже применительно не ко всей системе, а к определенным портам) или пустить через VPN. Например, можно разрешить определенным IP-адресам (из инета или из VPN) использовать сервис (например тот же ICMP), а всем остальным запретить.

Например (применительно к pf)

pass quick proto icmp from {XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ} to anydeny quick proto icmp from any to any

можно конечно еще написать какой-нибудь демон, который будет читать логи того же pfctl или ipfw и на основании их делать какие-либо изменения в конфигурации файерволла (подробнее можно, но долго, попробую как-нибудь позже написать)